# Laravel Eloquent Query To Display Data In Datatable For Each ID In Respective Row

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, datatables, yajra-datatable

Hey Stack Overflow Community,

I am in need of guidance as to how to approach this problem that I'm having. To make things clear, I have added the image of my current datatable below:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is that, my table should display each "Customer" in the order of the table headers. For instance, there are two data being displayed for "Ferb" who has Customer3 and Customer1. What I want is for customer1 to go to the "0002" column instead of making a new row entirely.

Below is my function code:

```
   public function monitorStatAjax(Request $request){

    $monitor_date= strtr($request->monitor_date, '/', '-');
    $new_monitor_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($monitor_date))." 00:00:00";

    $service_calls = ServiceCall::where('appointment_date', $new_monitor_date)
    ->join('users', 'service_calls.staff_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('customers', 'service_calls.company_id', '=', 'customers.id')
    ->join('servicecall_staff_statuses', 'service_calls.id', '=', 'servicecall_staff_statuses.servicecall_id')
    ->join('statuses', 'statuses.id', '=', 'users.status')
    ->select('service_calls.id as service_id','servicecall_staff_statuses.servicecall_appointment_time as appointment_time',
    'customers.name as company_name','users.name as staff_name','servicecall_staff_statuses.work_status as work_status','statuses.title as status_name')
    ->orderBy('service_calls.id', 'asc')->get();

    return DataTables::of($service_calls)
    ->addColumn('staff_name', function($data1) {
        return $data1->staff_name.' ('.$data1->status_name.')';
    })
    ->addColumn('0001', function ($data1) use($service_calls) {
        if ($data1->work_status == null)
        {

            return $data1->company_name.' <ul id="menu" style="display:flex">  
                    <li style="margin: 0px 8px 0px -30px;"><span class="redstatus"></span></li>
                    </ul> ';
        }
        elseif ($data1->work_status == 1)
        {
            return $data1->company_name.' <ul id="menu" style="display:flex">
            <li style="margin: 0px 8px 0px -30px;"><span class="completestatus"></span></li>
            <li>Completed</li>
            </ul> ';
        }
        elseif ($data1->work_status == 2)
        {
            return $data1->company_name.' <ul id="menu" style="display:flex">
            <li style="margin: 0px 8px 0px -30px;"><span class="followupstatus"></span></li>
            <li style="white-space:nowrap">Follow Up</li>
            </ul> ';
        }
        else
        {
            return $data1->company_name.' <ul id="menu" style="display:flex">
            <li style="margin: 0px 8px 0px -30px;"><span class="yellowstatus"></span></li>
            </ul> ';
        }
    })
    ->rawColumns(['0001'])
        ->make(true);
}
```

My Datatable Ajax code:

```
    $(function () {
    var table = $('#table').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ],
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
            },
            url: '{!! route("admin.monitor.stat.ajax") !!}',
            type:"POST",
            data: { monitor_date: "{{$new_monitor_date}}",
        },
        },
        order: [[0, "desc"]],
        columns: [
            {data: 'staff_name', name: 'staff_name'},
            {data: '0001', name: '0001'},
        ],
    });
});
```

Hoping to get some feedback on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it myself. After hours and hours of research and finding little to no clue on how to do this, I decided to take a different approach. To anyone having the same issue, this is how I did it.

My table is static. My table will not go more than 0010, so I knew I had to make it constant for 10 columns. I made a new table called 'monitor' and referred each column with it's own foreign id. After that it's as simple as returning the datatable column with each of its own unique name.